# How to keep external libraries in proguard android

Tags: android, proguard

Hi I am using proguard in my android application and I am also using external libs and getting error for the class of that lib. How shoud I add this lib in proguard rules.

How I have added lib in the gradle:

```
 implementation "io.crossbar.autobahn:autobahn-android:${versionAutobahn}"
```

Here is what I have tried in proguard but not working for me I have also used `-keep` but no help

```
-dontwarn io.crossbar.autobahn-autobahn-android   
-dontwarn io.crossbar.autobahn.wamp.Client
-keep class autobahn.** { *; }
-keep class io.crossbar.** { *; }
```

How should I keep this lib in proguard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-keep` to keep the class from any packages, something like:

```
-keep class io.crossbar.** { *; }
```

`-dontwarn` will only ignore the warnings. With, `-keep` you can keep any classes, class fields, and methods.

For more detailed usage check: [ProGuard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage)

Also, there is a feature request on GitHub for this repo to support ProGuard, [here](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-java/issues/520).

Comment: It is giving me the error "Unresolved class name"

Comment: Sorry, as an example had mentioned `autobahn.**`, it has to be `-keep class io.crossbar.** { *; }`, as mentioned by AlphaOne, Editing my answer also for this

Comment: when you are getting this error? Can you brief what you are trying to do, or how you getting this error?

Comment: when I add this line to proguard file that time is giving me an error

Comment: with this above rule, it is working for me, try adding  as: `-keep class io.crossbar.autobahn.** { *; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232899/discussion-between-anand-and-harsh-shah).

Comment: yes, it is giving me an error in the file but when I run the project it worked thank you :)

Comment: okay, please accept the answer, if this helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the below?

```
-keep class io.crossbar.** { *; }
```

Comment: It is giving me the error "Unresolved class name"